# 'bundle install' seem to be failed when deploying by capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

trying to deploy my Rails app to a virtual host on VirtualBox.
I'm using capistrano to deploy my app, and using vagrant to manage virtual machine.

My capistrano setting is OK, because it works correctly on AWS.

All that I did is,

```
$ cap deploy:setup
```

then

```
$ cap deploy

....

  * 2013-05-24 11:09:35 11:09:35 == Currently executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/deploy/apps/appname/releases/20130524020935 && bundle install --gemfile /ho
me/deploy/apps/appname/releases/20130524020935/Gemfile --path /home/deploy/apps/appname/shared/b
undle --deployment --binstubs --without test development deploy"
    servers: ["cent1"]
    [cent1] executing command
 ** [out :: cent1] Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
```

Command stops here. No progress.

Why fetching gems failed?

When I tried on AWS, everthing works fine. Whats the difference?

Comment: Try the command shown in "executing" via SSH and you'll probably see some output or error.Also, it can take a long time on slow network for initial gems installation

Comment: can you try to execute it in cap shell

Comment: `$ DEBUG_RESOLVER=true bundle install --gemfile /home/deploy/apps/appname/releases/20130524020935/Gemfile --path /home/deploy/apps/appname/shared/bundle --deployment --binstubs --without test development deploy --verbose`



tried above command via SSH and it complete successfully. It took very long time than I expected - may be 1 hour or long.

thanks.